Changing app service deployment from using a container from ACR to CI from bitbucket repository
I currently have bitbucket pipeline building a docker image and pushing it to Azure Container Registry. The image from the ACR is Continuously deployed through an Azure App Service.
I don't want to use docker and want to integrate bitbucket with the app service directly.
I tried doing this with the following CLI command
az webapp deployment source config \
              --name <name> \
              --resource-group <group> \
              --repo-url https://bitbucket.org/<repo> \
              --branch <branch> \
              --git-token <token> \ 
              --verbose

I get the below error despite having the correct URL and git-token set up
location is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.models._models_py3.SourceControl'> and will be ignored
source_control_name is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.models._models_py3.SourceControl'> and will be ignored
location is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.models._models_py3.SiteSourceControl'> and will be ignored
Cannot find SourceControlToken with name Bitbucket.

How do I modify my deployment settings to point to Bitbucket and not deploy from Azure Container Registry anymore?

What is the current configuration of the Azure App Service (runtime stack, environment, etc.)?

Is the app service configured for a specific programming language (e.g., Node.js, .NET, Python)?

The app service is configured with a node18-lts runtime configuration.


I don't want to use docker and want to integrate bitbucket with the app service directly.


You need to create a new Azure Web App to integrate bitbucket without using Docker.
Because the old web app is Containerized and in the deployment centre you only find below options.


If want to integrate bitbucket to Azure App Service, Go to Deployment Center >Source > Bitbucket as shown below.

You need to provide the required details and save it as shown below.

If want to use Azure CLI use below command to deploy bitbucket repository to Azure App Service.
az webapp deployment source config --name <AzureWebAppName> --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --repo-url <BitbucketRepoURL> --branch <branch> --manual-integration


Azure App Service Output:

